# How to convert a stream to a HashMap (not Map) in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a stream, and I want to explicitly collect it into a HashMap. Right now, I'm doing something like

```
List<Item> listToTransform = //initialized and populated
HashMap<K, V> myHashMap = new HashMap<>();
listToTransform.stream().map(/* do my transformation here */)
.forEach(i -> myHashMap.put(i.getKey(), i.getValue()));
```

I was wondering if there was a way of using Collectors to explicitly get back a HashMap.

Comment: You can use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) with a supplier function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the overloads to the `Collectors.toMap` method will allow you to select a map implementation of your choice.

Unfortunately, one of the drawbacks to this overload is that it also requires a method to merge two values when they have the same key (though I often reference a method that always throws in that case).

```
HashMap<K, V> myHashMap = listToTransform.stream().map(/* do my transformation here */)
.collect(Item::getKey, Item::getValue, this::throwIllegalArgumentException, HashMap::new);
```

Comment: why is the merging function in your example just throwing an Exception? You could write it as : `(left, right) -> right` and it will act as the *replace* of the value of the key - just like `HashMap` naturally does...

Comment: That is another option.  My personal preference, if I'm not expecting more than one instance of a given key, is to throw if that happens.  That way, I know that something is actually wrong with either my data or my logic, and I can go and fix it accordingly (whereas adding `(left,right) -> right` hides this fact from me).